# Как убрать гласные буквы из массива

Tags: c#, массивы, visual-studio

Цель: из 10 элементов массива вывести в консоль только согласные буквы английского алфавита. Т.е. 'A' , 'E' , 'I' должны быть убраны.
Вопрос: Есть часть программы, как сделать так, чтобы гласные не выводились в консоль?

```
        char[] symbs4 = new char[10];
        symbs4[0] = 'A';
        for (int i = 1; i < symbs4.Length; i++)
        {

            symbs4[i] = (char)(symbs4[i-1] + 1);
            Console.WriteLine(symbs4[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Создай словарь гласных букв и сверяйся с ним.

Comment: Можно подробней? Я просто новичок и не слишком много понимаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var vowels = "АОИ"; //строка с гласными буквами

for (int i = 1; i < symbs4.Length; i++)
{

    symbs4[i] = (char)(symbs4[i - 1] + 1);
    if (!vowels.Contains(Char.ToUpper(symbs4[i])))
        Console.WriteLine(symbs4[i]);
}
```

Comment: Зачем вообще на такое отвечать? Чувак просто просит за него сделать лабу первокурсника, блин.

Comment: @Gordory Ну... какие-то попытки предоставлены.

Comment: @Gordory т.е. то, что во многих соседних вопросах люди просят сделать за них оплачиваемую работу - вас не смущает? :)

Comment: @Gordory лол, я просто решаю задачки с книжки по шарпу, в универе вообще не на программиста учусь, откуда такие выводы